# Eliminate part of a file in python

Tags: python, file

In the below file I have 3 occurrences of '.1'. I want to eliminate the last one and write the rest of file to a new file. Kindly suggest some way to do it in PYTHON and thank you all.

> d1dlwa_ a.1.1.1 (A:) Protozoan/bacterial hemoglobin {Ciliate (Paramecium caudatum) [TaxId: 5885]}
>   slfeqlggqaavqavtaqfyaniqadatvatffngidmpnqtnktaaflcaalggpnawt

Answer (score 7):

If the file's not too horrendously huge, by far the simplest approach is:

```
f = open('oldfile', 'r')
data = f.read()
f.close()

data = data.replace('.1.1.1', '.1.1')

f = open('newfile', 'w')
f.write(data)
f.close()
```

If the file IS horrendously huge, you'll need to read it and write it by pieces. For example, if each *line* ISN'T too horrendously huge:

```
inf = open('oldfile', 'r')
ouf = open('newfile', 'w')
for line in inf:
    line = line.replace('.1.1.1', '.1.1')
    ouf.write(line)
ouf.close()
inf.close()
```

Comment: Instead of data = data.replace('.1.1.1', '.1.1') you can use a regular expression to remove the last '.1' no matter how many there are.

import re

data = re.sub( '\.1\>', '', data )

Comment: @Steve, sure, you can do all sort of complicated things if you need them; "do the simplest thing that could possibly work" is the operating principle -- avoiding problems such as your code would give (use r'...', '\>' doesn't work in Python REs [that's word boundary in _vi_ REs; in Python it's r'\b'], AND once finally repaired your code removes ALL THREE occurrences of '.1', not just the last one...;-). Keeping it simple is thus very advisable.

Comment: @Arshan, always glad to help, but be sure to accept an answer that has helped you: that's the fundamental bit of SO etiquette!

Comment: the version that works with big file sizes is very clear and easy, I don't see why it shouldn't be used even if the files are small.

Comment: @nosklo: speed. Measure both versions on a million files of a few megabytes each.

Answer (score 4):

Works with any size file:

```
open('newfile', 'w').writelines(line.replace('.1.1.1', '.1.1') 
                                for line in open('oldfile'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have something like this :

```
line = line.split(" ")
line[0] = line[0][0:line[0].rindex(".")]
print " ".join(line)
```

Not the prettiest code, but from my console tests, it works.